# Smooth camera movement for car selection menu in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a car select screen for my game. I can move camera with mouse around my car. Camera moves only when I hold the mouse button. When I release mouse button, camera stops instantly. But I want to stop camera slowly. I don't want to use Cinemachine. So, how can I stop my camera slowly when I release the mouse button? This is the code I am currently using:

```
public class MenuCameraMovement : MonoBehaviour

public Transform car;
private float sensitivity = 2f;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        float rotateHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float rotateVertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        //For rotating
        transform.RotateAround(car.transform.position, Vector3.up, rotateHorizontal * sensitivity);

        //No need vertical rotation
        //transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, transform.right, rotateVertical * sensitivity);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like (not debugged):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuCameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform car;
    private float sensitivity = 2f;
    private bool movementStarted;

    private float sesitivityDecrease = 100f; // 100 is random. Play with it until it is ok

    private void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            movementStarted = true;
            float rotateHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            float rotateVertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            //For rotating
            transform.RotateAround(car.transform.position, Vector3.up, rotateHorizontal * sensitivity);

            //No need vertical rotation
            //transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, transform.right, rotateVertical * sensitivity);

        } else {
            if (movementStarted) {
                if (sesitivityDecrease > 0) {
                    transform.RotateAround(car.transform.position, Vector3.up, sesitivityDecrease);
                    sesitivityDecrease--;
                } else {
                    movementStarted = false;
                    sesitivityDecrease = 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can play araound with the `sesitivityDecrease` value until the effect you are after is the correct one.

Another approach is to do it with a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: Thank you for help! But there was a little issue about rotating -x axis. The problem was, if I rotate my mouse on -x axis, sensitivityDecrease variable was still going for x axis. But I solved that. Thank you for help again!

Comment: glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MenuCameraMovement : MonoBehaviour

public Transform car;
private float sensitivity = 2f;

private float rotateHorizontal;
//private float rotateVertical;

private bool movementStarted;

private float sensitivityDecrease;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        movementStarted = true;

        rotateHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        //rotateVertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        //This if else statement made for the rotation bug
        //When you rotate x axis, camera slow downs correctly but,
        //when you rotate -x axis, camera still moves x direction to slow down
        //It has to move -x direction. To solve that, check our Mouse X is less than zero or not 
        if (rotateHorizontal < 0)
            //If camera moving -x axis, we set our sensitivityDecrease to -100
            //That means our camera will slow down on -x axis
            sensitivityDecrease = -100;

        else
            sensitivityDecrease = 100;

        //For rotating
        transform.RotateAround(car.transform.position, Vector3.up, rotateHorizontal * sensitivity);
    }

    else
    {
        if (movementStarted)
        {
            if (sensitivityDecrease > 0)
            {
                //Also added Time.deltaTime to add smoothness
                transform.RotateAround(car.transform.position, Vector3.up, sensitivityDecrease * Time.deltaTime);
                sensitivityDecrease--;
            }
            else
            {
                movementStarted = false;
            }
        }

            else if (sensitivityDecrease < 0)
            {
                transform.RotateAround(car.transform.position, Vector3.up, sensitivityDecrease * Time.deltaTime);
                sensitivityDecrease++;
            }
            else
            {
                movementStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the debugged final version the code.